# Why do different devices use the same session in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I use the session to count the number of failed logins.
But when I use Wi-Fi internet, because the IP of two devices (mobile and PC) is the same, Django uses the same session.
If I have two failed logins on PC and two failed logins on mobile, it will add these two together.
But the interesting thing is that when I log into the account from one device, the second device does not log into the account and must be logged into the account separately.
That is, it uses two different storage methods to log into the account and count the number of unsuccessful logins.

```
if 'RC' in request.session:
   VRC = request.session['RC']
else:
        VRC = 1
      
VRC += 1
request.session['RC'] = VRC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All devices using the same Wi-Fi have the same external IP, what you mentioned as a problem is actually an advantage that prevents malicious attacks on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Django's default session implementation uses cookies to store session data. Since both your PC and mobile share the same Wi-Fi and therefore the same external IP, the session cookie is shared.